# Python get MAC addresses of devices when not on wifi

Tags: python, ios, iphone, bluetooth, wifi

I am working on a project that requires knowing the bluetooth or wifi MAC adresses of local IOS devices but whenever the IOS device is not in the settings screen for bluetooth, the device is not discoverable. This is a problem because the program needs to scan all local IOS devices no matter if the settings screen is open. I am considering switching to using wifi mac addresses if there is a way to extract them when not being connected to the same network or even on a network at all just in the same area. It wouldn't need to be long-range only find some sort of always-broadcasting unique identifier short distances (I know IP adresses can change so I avoided using them) that can be found without being connected to a certain wifi or being discoverable on bluetooth. Is there a solution that would work with python and IOS? Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Even when discoverable you will find that the Bluetooth MAC address periodically randomises unless you have paired with the device.  This is for privacy and to prevent tracking.

Comment: Is there any other unique identifier I can use to check if I am within distance of someone also running my app? I am trying to use kivy to build this.

Comment: If they are running your app then it can advertise a peripheral via core Bluetooth and your app can look for that and connect to it and obtain a unique identifier. Apple has put a lot of effort into ensuring that devices can't be identified uniquely by arbitrary scanning.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a specific package for core bluetooth?